# Compare password of current user with model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, web-applications

This might be a really dumb question (I'm new to ASP.NET).

Anyways, I'm making a web application for practice that will manage students and their courses of a school. The information of the student's courses, student id number, name, grade etc. will be stored on Student objects in the database. When an admin adds a student to the database, it will add a user account with the student's name as the username, and the randomly generated 7-digit student id number as the password.

When the student is logged in, is there anyway that I can get the student model from the database that corresponds to the logged-in student with comparing the student-number to the password? Would there be a better or more secure approach to getting the corresponding user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If password is randomly generated 7 digit number, there is a possibility that passwords can be duplicated unless you set the database password columns to unique. Personally I would avoid such approach as it creates more problems in future. Why not to get user object by user id?

Comment: In the function that generates the student id, it checks the database first before assigning it to avoid duplicates, but you're right. I probably should change the column to unique. If i store the id of the user that the model corresponds to in the student model, would that be a secure approach? Thanks for the answer by the way.